# more happy as a comparative

Tags: grammar, comparatives

I wonder if "more happy" could be used as a comparative. For example, "He is more happy than me". Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Not morphologically. _Happy_ is a two-syllable adjective ending in /i/, so it has to take the _-er_ suffix instead of using _more_. A correct sentence is _He is happier than me_.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler says in comment above, 'happier' is generally better. But 'more happy' appears quite commonly in literature ([example from Anthony Trollope](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dGVODwAAQBAJ&pg=PT29912&dq=%22%20be%20more%20happy%22#v=onepage&q=%22%20be%20more%20happy%22&f=false), [another from Anne Thackeray](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MJYvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA321&dq=%22%20be%20more%20happy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj56ufPlsLmAhV0lFwKHYaaBk4Q6AEIYjAI#v=onepage&q=%22%20be%20more%20happy%22&f=false)) and in expressions such as "[7 ways to be more happy](https://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/london-life/how-to-be-happy-improve-quality-of-life-ceo-the-happiness-research-institute-a4095886.html)".